# NHibernate fetchmany Object does not match the destination type

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am trying to solve the n+1 issue, where I retrieve all my forumthreads and posts. I tried to do it like the following:

```
return Session.Query<ForumThread>().Where(x => x.IsActive)
                                   .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastForumPost)
                                   .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                                   .Take(pageSize)
                                   .FetchMany(x=>x.ForumPosts)
                                   .Cacheable();
```

But this gives an error:

```
Object does not match the destination type.
```

If I remove .Cacheable() it works. Is there any known error with fetching and using query caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this was fixed in 3.1 (see https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2502), although other bug numbers suggest otherwise.

If you're not using 3.1, try upgrading.

Comment: Thanks, I just hate the procedure of having to compile e.g. NHibernate.Search and all the other stuff just to use a new version.